# How to check if a file has overlay icon in Windows 7 using AutoIt

Tags: automation, ui-automation, autoit

I have an application which adds a tick mark (overlay icon) on the file icon (similar to the tick mark on files checked out from SVN repositories)  after successful execution. I would like to detect through AutoIt whether the overlay icon is present for that file or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [_ImageSearch](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/65748-image-search-library/) library.

Do a printscreen with icon with overlay visible and then cut the small inner piece of the overlay and save it as a BMP.
Then use that image along with _ImageSearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [_WinAPI_ShellGetImageList](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/161946-system-image-lists-for-extra-large-and-jumbo-icons/)

Comment: can you please ellaborate on how I can use this function. I see that there is a function called GetSystemImageListIcon but it returns 7 for any file that I pass to it.